# looping through two arrays and using jax.cond to apply different function when they have same index

Tags: python, jax

I am struggling with the functional programming theme of Jax. I am trying to implement this using jax, especially how to build the pred of `jax.cond` for the index match for two arrays. The equivalent function/ minimal example is below.

```
odd = np.array([1,3,5,7,9])
even =  np.array([0,2,6,8,10])
Kmat = np.zeros((even.shape[0], odd.shape[0]))
for i, elm1 in enumerate(odd):
  for j, elm2 in enumerate(even):
    if i==j:
      Kmat[i,j] = 0
    else:
      Kmat[i,j] = elm1 - elm2
```

this is what i tried

```
arr1 = np.array([1,3,5,7,9])
arr2 =  np.array([0,2,6,8,10])

x = np.arange(arr1.shape[0])
y = np.arange(arr2.shape[0])

f1 = lambda _ : 0
f2 = lambda x,y,arr1, arr2 : arr1[x]- arr2[y]
predVec = np.eye(arr1.shape[0], dtype=bool) 
func = lambda pred : jax.lax.cond(pred,f1,f2, [x,y,arr1, arr2])
jax.vmap(func)(predVec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid loops and conditionals here and use numpy-style broadcasting instead. For example:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
i = jnp.arange(len(odd))[:, None]
j = jnp.arange(len(even))
Kmat = jnp.where(i == j, 0.0, odd[:, None] - even)
print(Kmat)
```

```
[[ 0. -1. -5. -7. -9.]
 [ 3.  0. -3. -5. -7.]
 [ 5.  3.  0. -3. -5.]
 [ 7.  5.  1.  0. -3.]
 [ 9.  7.  3.  1.  0.]]
```

Alternatively, if you're working with functions `f1` and `f2` that require scalar inputs (and are JAX-compatible), you could express this using a nested `vmap` transform:

```py
from jax import vmap
import jax.numpy as jnp
from functools import partial

odd = jnp.array([1,3,5,7,9])
even =  jnp.array([0,2,6,8,10])

def f1(x, y):
  assert x.ndim == y.ndim == 0
  return 0

def f2(x, y):
  assert x.ndim == y.ndim == 0
  return x - y

@partial(vmap, in_axes=(0, None))
@partial(vmap, in_axes=(None, 0))
def g(i, j):
  return jnp.where(i == j, f1(odd[i], even[j]), f2(odd[i], even[j]))

Kmat = g(jnp.arange(len(odd)), jnp.arange(len(even)))
print(Kmat)
```

```
[[ 0 -1 -5 -7 -9]
 [ 3  0 -3 -5 -7]
 [ 5  3  0 -3 -5]
 [ 7  5  1  0 -3]
 [ 9  7  3  1  0]]
```

Comment: thank you for your response. is there a way to make the jnp.where(i==j, f1,f2) where f1 and f2 are general function which take the individual ith and jth element? Thanks again!

Comment: `Kmat = jnp.where(i == j, f1(i,j), f2(i,j))` does not work. It complains only scalar argument are to be provided.

Comment: OK, see the edited answer for another approach that works with two JAX-compatible functions expecting scalar inputs.